# Checking to see if an array that is part of an object is empty

Tags: php, drupal, if-statement

This is in Drupal but should be applicable for normal PHP.

field-event-address is an array that is under `$entity_fetched`.

```
<?php if ($entity_fetched->field-event-address != "") echo $entity_fetched->field-event-address['und']['0']['value']; ?>
```

For some reason, when I do this, I get this error if I leave the `['und']['0']['value']` off:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field in eval() (line 7 of /opt/staging/contitemp/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(125) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Use of undefined constant event - assumed 'event' in eval() (line 7 of /opt/staging/contitemp/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(125) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Use of undefined constant address - assumed 'address' in eval() (line 7 of /opt/staging/contitemp/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(125) : eval()'d code).
```

And this error if I leave it on:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /opt/staging/contitemp/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(125) : eval()'d code on line 7
```

I am trying to create an if statement that checks to see if the array under the object is empty or not, and if it isn't, echos the array contents.

I'm really scratching my head with this one - I should be able to just check if an array is empty if it's under an object, correct?

Comment: what does var_dump($entity_fetched->field-event-address) give you ?

Answer (score 1):

`-` sign can't be used in variables names in PHP. Because of that you're getting syntax error (or undefined constant when PHP is trying to understand what did you mean).

Instead you can change name to `$entity_fetched->fieldEventAddress` (it's still readable and now it's correct).

Comment: Ah, the way Drupal does this confused me - it has a token system that uses the - character, whereas when it is switched to PHP variables, it switches it to an _ character. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal, you really should be using entity metadata wrappers.

So your code would be something like:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('entity_type', $fetched_entity);
$value = $wrapper->field_name->value();
if (!empty($value)) echo $value;
```

You can find more information about entity metadata wrappers here:
https://drupal.org/node/1021556